# Redirecting in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit, laravel-routing, codeception

I am performing a functional test with Codeception powered by PHP unit.

I am coming from a form and would like to redirect back to the home page

```
$I->fillField('Username:', 'JohnDoe');
$I->fillField('Email:', 'john@example.com');
$I->fillField('Password:', 'demo');
$I->fillField('Password_confirmation', 'demo');

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/');
$I->see('Register');
```

The code used for redirecting 
**Registration Controller**

```
public function store()
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', [
'as' => 'home',
'uses' => 'PagesController@home'
```

]);

In the browser the application works as expected but when I am running the functional test I get this error

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'/'
+'/register'
```

It is as if the page is not redirecting from '/register' (registration page) to '/'(home page)

How can I rectify this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Redirect::route('home') in the store() method?

Comment: I have tried this but I am still getting the same error that it is expecting '/' yet it is getting '/register'

Comment: Can you please also post the code for the /register route in routes.php and also the code of the form? Thanks!

Comment: Actually the issue may be that you're not actually submitting the form. You can do:

$I->submitForm('#login', array('login' => 'davert', 'password' => '123456')); 

(taken from Laravel4 module doc for Codeception)